# What does で mean in the end of a sentence in Hida dialect

Tags: grammar, particle-で, dialects, sentence-final-particles

> 明日は私が作るでね〜

Is the で in this sentence the particle で？ what is the function of で in this case?

This is from 君の名は manga and one of the settings of the story is in Gifu prefecture so this seems to be a Hida dialect (?)

I also found [this link](http://www.ctk.ne.jp/%7Eyamamoto/hida_dialect/grm/bm2/grammar084.html) but I can’t fully understand the explanation:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

飛騨弁 is not the only recognized dialect spoken in the geographical region that is modern-day 岐阜県 (Gifu Prefecture). Two main dialects are recognized in 岐阜県, the other one being 美濃弁 ([Mino dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mino_dialect)).

> The Mino dialect (美濃弁, Mino-ben) is a Japanese dialect spoken in the southern area, made up of the former area known as Mino Province, of Gifu Prefecture, Japan. It is also referred to as the Tōnō dialect (東濃弁 Tōnō-ben) by residents of the Tōnō region of the prefecture, which is the eastern part of the former province. It is sometimes also referred to as the Gifu dialect (岐阜弁 Gifu-ben), but that can sometimes include Hida dialect, which is in the northern part of Gifu Prefecture.

This で you are asking about is explained on [美濃弁's Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E6%BF%83%E5%BC%81):

> 理由の接続助詞には主に「で」や「もんで」を用いる。例：「やっとくで」（やっておくから）。

More of the dialogue whence your line is taken:

> 四葉: お姉ちゃん、遅い！
> 三葉: 明日は私が作るでね。

So

> 明日は私が作るでね〜

basically means

> 明日は私が作るからね～
> I will cook breakfast tomorrow (so stop complaining)